# Difficulty POSTing multipart/form-data in tcl rest

Tags: rest, post, tcl, multipartform-data

I'm trying to POST an image in tcllib's rest package as part of a multipart/form-data document.  I believe I just need to format the payoad properly.

The url looks like:

```
POST /api/v1/rawImage/1000?slice=1
```

I can do this easily with curl (and other things as well) with:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F imageFile=@../../images/data/Image_1.bin http://${HOST}/api/v1/rawImage/1000?slice=1
```

In looking through rest.tcl, I don't see anything that explictly formats the boundaries for the payload.

Here is what I have to try the POST:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

package require rest
package require json

# pull in Image data
set fh [open "Image_1.bin"]
fconfigure $fh -encoding binary -translation lf
set filedata [read $fh]
close $fh
puts "filedata length: [string length $filedata]"

# POST request
set url http://localhost:5007/api/v1/rawImage/100?slice=1
set header [list content-type multipart/form-data]
set config [list format json method post headers $header]

set form_data {rawImage $filedata}

set res [::rest::simple $url {} $config $form_data]

puts $res
```

The following HTTP header is seen wireshark:

[image: Wireshark trace]

Comment: If you are sending only one file, why use a multipart form?

Comment: Understood.  The example is trying to demonstrate the basic problem.  Also, swagger schema definition requires multipart/form-data even for a single file upload.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look to the [create interface command documentation](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/rest/rest.html#13), the example of Google Docs.

Also, if you want to know more about the mime boundary string, you also could see the proc ***mime_multipart*** in the [source code of "rest"](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/artifact/88376cd34c972c73).

Comment: Thanks for these comments.  I did take a look at the gdocs example.  In fact, some of my sample code comes from the gdocs example.  The mime_multipart while seeming to move closer to a solution, produces multipart/related formatted document.  Thanks again.